# Adding an operation to Content Types

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm working on a module. I've added a tab to each Content Type in `hook_menu` using something like:

```
$items['admin/structure/types/manage/%/stuff'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage stuff',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('stuff_content_type_stuff_form', 4),
    'access arguments' => array('administer content types'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 100
);
```

The tab appears fine when I visit `admin/structure/types/manage/article/edit`, for example. However, when I view `admin/structure/types` to view the list of content types, I'd like to see "Manage stuff" listed as a link in the "operations" column alongside "Manage fields" and "Manage display".

Is this possible? Can someone please provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `admin/structure/types` page is created via the [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in the node module:

```
$items['admin/structure/types'] = array(
  'title' => 'Content types',
  'description' => 'Manage content types, including default status, front page promotion, comment settings, etc.',
  'page callback' => 'node_overview_types',
  'access arguments' => array('administer content types'),
  'file' => 'content_types.inc',
);
```

which shows that the page is generated by the `node_overview_types` function in `content_types.inc`:

```
/**
 * Displays the content type admin overview page.
 */
function node_overview_types() {
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  $names = node_type_get_names();
  $field_ui = module_exists('field_ui');
  $header = array(t('Name'), array('data' => t('Operations'), 'colspan' => $field_ui ? '4' : '2'));
  $rows = array();

  foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
    $type = $types[$key];
    if (node_hook($type->type, 'form')) {
      $type_url_str = str_replace('_', '-', $type->type);
      $row = array(theme('node_admin_overview', array('name' => $name, 'type' => $type)));
      // Set the edit column.
      $row[] = array('data' => l(t('edit'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str));

      if ($field_ui) {
        // Manage fields.
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('manage fields'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/fields'));

        // Display fields.
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('manage display'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/display'));
      }

      // Set the delete column.
      if ($type->custom) {
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('delete'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/delete'));
      }
      else {
        $row[] = array('data' => '');
      }

      $rows[] = $row;
    }
  }

  $build['node_table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No content types available. <a href="@link">Add content type</a>.', array('@link' => url('admin/structure/types/add'))),
  );

  return $build;
}
```

So, one way I can see to do this would be to in your module, do a [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and point the page callback to a function in your module and just add to the core one's functionality, eg, something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {

  $items['admin/structure/types']['page callback']='YOURMODULE_node_overview_types';
  unset($items['admin/structure/types']['file']); // or point it to YOURMODULE_pages.inc if need be

}
```

and then basically just copy the code from `node_overview_types()` into `YOURMODULE_node_overview_types()` and then put in your functionality, eg, change the colspan to 5 or 3 and add in the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to your menu item.

NOTE:  Of course, if the node module is ever updated you'll have to keep that in mind and possibly redo this.  So, yes, since a render array is returned, you could instead modify this in any number of hook alters before the page is rendered. If you want to look into this approach, [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/930760) is a good place to start.

ADDITION:

For completeness, this is one way you could use a [hook_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7):

```
function YOURMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {

  if ($_GET['q']=='admin/structure/types') {

    $types = array_keys(node_type_get_types());

    $page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#header'][1]['colspan']++;
    foreach($page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#rows'] as $type => &$row) {
      $row[]='New menu link goes here for ' . $types[$type];
    }

  }

}
```

instead of the `hook_menu_alter()` approach above.  But also, obviously, it too relies on the structure of the array returned by the node module.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a hybrid of your two suggestions after seeing just the first. I implemented `hook_menu_alter`, and replaced the page callback, but rather than re-implementing, I passed the original callback as a parameter to mine. From my callback, I called the original callback (`node_overview_types()`), modified the results (as you do in `hook_page_alter`), then returned that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, I have a suggestion for you

dont forget clear cache after apply this,

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {

      $items['admin/structure/types']['page callback']='yourmodule_node_overview_types',
    }


function yourmodule_node_overview_types() {
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  $names = node_type_get_names();
  $field_ui = module_exists('field_ui');
  $header = array(t('Name'), array('data' => t('Operations'), 'colspan' => $field_ui ? '4' : '2'));
  $rows = array();

  foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
    $type = $types[$key];
    if (node_hook($type->type, 'form')) {
      $type_url_str = str_replace('_', '-', $type->type);
      $row = array(theme('node_admin_overview', array('name' => $name, 'type' => $type)));
      // Set the edit column.
      $row[] = array('data' => l(t('edit'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str));
      $row[] = array('data' => l(t('Manage stuff'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/%/stuff' . $type_url_str));

      if ($field_ui) {
        // Manage fields.
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('manage fields'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/fields'));

        // Display fields.
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('manage display'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/display'));
      }

      // Set the delete column.
      if ($type->custom) {
        $row[] = array('data' => l(t('delete'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type_url_str . '/delete'));
      }
      else {
        $row[] = array('data' => '');
      }

      $rows[] = $row;
    }
  }

  $build['node_table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No content types available. <a href="@link">Add content type</a>.', array('@link' => url('admin/structure/types/add'))),
  );

  return $build;
}
```