# Programmatically created content type don't have a delete link

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm developing a module that creates new content types through form that I created (not in hook_install):

```
function create_new_content_type($type, $name){
    $t = get_t();

    $new_node = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $name,
        'base' => 'node_content',
        //'description' => 'This is an example node type with a few fields.',
    );
    $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($new_node);
    node_add_body_field($content_type);

    // Check if we create content type or update.
    $status = node_type_save($content_type);

    // Replacement rule for the messages.
    $t_args = array('%name' => $content_type->name);

    if ($status == SAVED_NEW) { // create case
        watchdog('node', 'Added content type %name.', $t_args, WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l($t('view'), 'admin/structure/types'));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I go to `admin/structure/types` these I don't see the delete link.
I found here some similar questions that suggest to remove with `/admin/structure/types/manage/<content-type-name>/delete` but it's not a good solution for me. 
Is it possible to display that link?

**EDIT:**
This is what I mean:
[image]

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://drupal.org/node/1055460) in Drupal core. And currently there's no fix to it apart from appending `/delete` at the end of the url. Why is it not a good solution for you? Do you not have a listing page of some sort that lists the content types you created through this form? Then if not, maybe create one, and manually create the links with `/delete` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always take the dull axe approach and use a page_alter, eg, something along the lines of

```
function YOURMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {

  if ($_GET['q']=='admin/structure/types') {

    $page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#rows'][]=array(
      'Foo <small>(Machine name: foo)</small><div class="description">Here is my description of foo</div>',
      array('data' => l(t('edit'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/foo')),
      array('data' => l(t('manage fields'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/foo/fields')),
      array('data' => l(t('manage display'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/foo/display')),
      array('data' => l(t('delete'), 'admin/structure/types/manage/foo/delete')),
    );

  }

}
```

which will create a row for type `foo`.

Per additions to the question:  since the row is showing up but just without the `delete` link, you can go in and create it similarly, eg,

```
$page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#rows'][NUM][4]=array('data' => l('delete', 'admin/structure/types/manage/foo/delete'));
```

where `NUM` is the row number where your content type is found. You might also want to check out [Adding an operation to Content Types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/adding-an-operation-to-content-types/101039#101039) and the page_alter() there on a possible way you might be able to easily figure out `NUM`.

Another addition:

Could you just do this in your module:

```
$info = array(
    'type' => $type,
    'name' => $name,
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'custom' => TRUE, // fake it out to think it was made via the UI...
);
$content_type = node_type_set_defaults($info);
```

A cursory glance through the code and [node_type_set_defaults()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_set_defaults/7) suggests that the only thing this does is allow this delete link to be presented in this very form.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Is that more clear?

Comment: Sure, you can "add in" the delete link via the second method mentioned in my answer above.

Comment: The 'custom' => TRUE, worked